# How to construct Bayesian belief network in java ? Is there any library ? API?

Tags: java, machine-learning, feature-selection, naivebayes, bayesian-networks

Assume I have a dataset with 10 features and one class level. Now, I want to construct Bayesian belief network among the features. How I would be able to do that in java ?

Is there any API or machine learning library ?
Any hints or any starting point will be appreciated.

Comment: The learning tool Samiam is implemented in Java. See http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/index.php. You need to register, then it can be freely downloaded. There is a jar file included, I think it is called inflib.jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to be specially performant, it's possible to embed [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) on your application. You could also use its graphical inteface to conveniently test your model.

On the other hand, if you need very high performance, it may not be a good choice.

Comment: is it possible to find the causal relationship among variables using Weka?

Comment: This other question should help you, at least in part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498567/finding-a-correlation-between-variable-and-class-variable